# How to make a Flutter painter APP with layers

Tags: android, flutter, paint, photoshop, custom-painter

I want to make a painter APP with layers like PhotoShop, and I choose Flutter as the language.
The problem is that I don't know how to make the layers with high performance, because I have tried `CustomPainter` following online tutorials and open source codes, but the speed of painting is slow if I draw many strokes.
After further study, I find that the difference between Flutter and other platforms is that the canvas offered by `CustomPainter` always needs to be repainted even if I just draw a new stroke.
Please help me.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.